# Use fetch to get JSON Data for Chart JS

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js, fetch

I am new to async coding and going crazy trying to work out a solution to load data from a nested json array file into Chart JS. Combing through all the various examples, I can get at the data inside of the fetch call but cant get it out into a global object since its async. The goal is to reference the json fields and values in the chart configuration. Here is the current iteration...

```js
var jsonData =
fetch('dataSummary.json')
  .then(status)
  .then(json)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data[0]);
    return data[0]
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });

var chartData = {jsonData:{}};
Promise.all([jsonData]).then(function(values){
    chartData = values[0];
    console.log(chartData);
    return chartData[0];
});

console.log(Object.keys(chartData))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to update (or to draw) the chart *when* the data is ready.

```
fetch('dataSummary.json')
    .then(res => json)
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data[0]);
        // rather the returning data use it to update/populate the chart
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved the chart definition into the fetch and it works.